# Can't get jit-grunt to work

Tags: gruntjs

I'm trying to use jit-grunt to speed up my workflow, but it keeps returning the error:

```
jit-grunt: Plugin for the "watch" task not found.
```

My jit-grunt code:

```
require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    "uglify" : "grunt-contrib-uglify",
    "image-min" : "grunt-contrib-imagemin",
    "watch" : "grunt-contrib-watch",
    "sass": "grunt-contrib-sass",
    "browser-sync" : "grunt-browser-sync",
    "newer" : "grunt-newer"
});
```

My register task code:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
```

The modules are all there, as they work with the normal grunt.loadNpmTasks method. Any idea what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: `npm install grunt-contrib-watch`?

Comment: You shouldn't even need that static mapping in your config object as it should pick up grunt-contrib-watch automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to update grunt version to 0.4 or higher.